# JavaFX application to run on mobile platforms

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Can we develop an application using JavaFX and run it on multiple platforms, including mobile(Android, iOS) and Desktop(Windows, Mac, Linux) as well?

Comment: you managed to pass three-and-a-half years without doing any research on your own? *head-shaking

Answer (score 1):

Latest Oracle MAF (2.1.2) runs on both Android and iOS.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/documentation/maf212certmatrix-2524539.html

Support for Windows phones it has been in talks for a while, it will won't be long until Oracle will make it available.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX is supported on Windows, Mac and Linux. It is not supported on iOS or Android although there are third party solutions provided by the community for that (RoboVM for iOS). This might be the reason you were unable to find instructions on how to set up Android Studio with JavaFX.

Generally JavaFX 8 is very reliable on all three platforms. Please note that JavaFX 1 is an entirely different thing than JavaFX 2 and 8. Not only does it rely on JavaFX Script instead of Java, it also focusses more on browsers and mobile devices.